# Maya Python - Connecting UI to functions

Tags: python, function, user-interface, maya

I am working on creating a little Bullet Spray Generator to be run in maya using Python and I'm stuck on how to take the values inputted by the user in the UI and use them in functions. The `bulletSpread` function needs to take the value from  `createGunUI`, specifically the `DistCtrl` slider and multiply it by a value in the `GunDictionary` to get the spread. Simply put, I just need to know how to take the inputted values from a slider in UI and use them in functions.

I've included my code below, any help would be very much appreciated!

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random
import math

    #Dictionary containing weapon names and presets - presets contain values for shot sliders, distance sliders and multipliers for spread calculation
GunDictionary = {}
GunDictionary["weapon"] = ["Pistol", "Shotgun", "SMG", "Sniper", "RPG"]
GunDictionary["weaponSelected"] = GunDictionary["weapon"][0]
GunDictionary["Pistol_preset"] = [(1,18,9), (10,50,25), (0.1)]
GunDictionary["Shotgun_preset"] = [(1,4,2), (10,50,25), (0.3)]
GunDictionary["SMG_preset"] = [(5,30,15), (10,50,25), (0.2)]
GunDictionary["Sniper_preset"] = [(1,3,2), (10,50,25), (0.05)]
GunDictionary["RPG_preset"] = [(1,2,1), (10,50,25), (0)]

    #Initial cleanup of UIs
if (cmds.window("Gun_Select", exists = True)): 
    cmds.deleteUI("Gun_Select")

    #Initial cleanup of scene
cmds.select(all=True)
cmds.delete()


    #Fire button condition - creates wall
def goShoot(gunSelected, numOfShots, *pArgs): 
    print "Begin"
    weaponName = GunDictionary["weaponSelected"]
    cmds.deleteUI(weaponName)
    createWall()
    bulletSpread(GunDictionary["weaponSelected"])


    #Cancel UI2 - deletes UI2
def cancelShoot(*pArgs):
    print "cancel"
    weaponName = GunDictionary["weaponSelected"]
    cmds.deleteUI(weaponName)

    #Cancel UI1 - deletes UI1
def cancelSelect(*pArgs):
    print "cancel"
    cmds.deleteUI("Gun_Select")


    #Function to create wall
def createWall():
    wall = cmds.polyCube(h=10, w=15, d=1, name='wall')
    cmds.move(0,5,0, 'wall')



newRange = 0;
    #Function to generate bullet spread
def bulletSpread(gunSelected, distance):
    weaponName = GunDictionary["weaponSelected"]
    multiplier = GunDictionary[weaponName + "_preset"][2]
    distance = ???
    newRange = distance * multiplier
    print newRange



    #Function to create drop-down menu in createSelectUI
def printNewMenuItem(item):
    print item
    GunDictionary["weaponSelected"] = item
    return GunDictionary["weaponSelected"]



    #Function to take weapon selected in UI1 and call UI2, also calls function to calculate bullet spread
def ui_refreshSelWeapon(fun, *args):
    createGunUI(GunDictionary["weaponSelected"])



    #UI allowing user to pick from a selection of Guns in a drop-down menu
def createSelectUI(): 
    cmds.window("Gun_Select")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    GunSelectCtrl = cmds.optionMenu(label='Gun', changeCommand=printNewMenuItem)
    for i in GunDictionary["weapon"]:
        cmds.menuItem(label=i)

    cmds.button(label = "Continue", command = ui_refreshSelWeapon)

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelSelect)

    cmds.showWindow("Gun_Select")

createSelectUI()



weapon_uiDic = {}

    #Called after gun select, allows user to choose the number of shots and distance from wall
def createGunUI(gunSelected):

    weaponName = GunDictionary["weaponSelected"]

    if cmds.window(weaponName, exists=True):
       cmds.deleteUI(weaponName)

    cmds.window(weaponName)
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Gun_Select")

    numBullets = GunDictionary[weaponName + "_preset"][0]
    distToTarget = GunDictionary[weaponName + "_preset"][1]

    weapon_uiDic["NumBulletsCtrl"] = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
                                                       minValue=numBullets[0], maxValue=numBullets[1], value=numBullets[2], field=True)

    weapon_uiDic["DistCtrl"] = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
                                                 minValue=distToTarget[0], maxValue=distToTarget[1], value=distToTarget[2], field=True)

    weapon_uiDic["fireButton"] = cmds.button(label = "Fire", 
                                            command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(weapon_uiDic["NumBulletsCtrl"], 
                                            query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(weapon_uiDic["DistCtrl"], query=True, value=True)))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow(weaponName)
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced your lambda function by partial module. It is also used to pass some args through maya UI.

I don't understand why you don't track your distance data through the different functions.
You just have to read your code and print the values at each step to see where it goes, if you don't understand their flow.
Why in "goShoot", you define a variable gunSelected to be inputed if you use your GunDictionary["weaponSelected"] instead of Gunselected.
In your "bulletSpread", you specify three args and input only one under your "goShoot".
It can't work if your functions are not linked properly.

you can find , my version of your code below :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random
import math
from functools import partial

    #Dictionary containing weapon names and presets - presets contain values for shot sliders, distance sliders and multipliers for spread calculation
GunDictionary = {}
GunDictionary["weapon"] = ["Pistol", "Shotgun", "SMG", "Sniper", "RPG"]
GunDictionary["weaponSelected"] = GunDictionary["weapon"][0]
GunDictionary["Pistol_preset"] = [(1,18,9), (10,50,25), (0.1)]
GunDictionary["Shotgun_preset"] = [(1,4,2), (10,50,25), (0.3)]
GunDictionary["SMG_preset"] = [(5,30,15), (10,50,25), (0.2)]
GunDictionary["Sniper_preset"] = [(1,3,2), (10,50,25), (0.05)]
GunDictionary["RPG_preset"] = [(1,2,1), (10,50,25), (0)]

    #Initial cleanup of UIs
if (cmds.window("Gun_Select", exists = True)): 
    cmds.deleteUI("Gun_Select")

    #Initial cleanup of scene
cmds.select(all=True)
cmds.delete()


    #Fire button condition - creates wall
def goShoot(gunSelected, numOfShots, distance, *pArgs): 
    print "Begin"
    weaponName = gunSelected
    cmds.deleteUI(weaponName)
    createWall()
    bulletSpread(GunDictionary["weaponSelected"], distance)


#Cancel UI2 - deletes UI2
def cancelShoot(*pArgs):
    print "cancel"
    weaponName = GunDictionary["weaponSelected"]
    cmds.deleteUI(weaponName)

#Cancel UI1 - deletes UI1
def cancelSelect(*pArgs):
    print "cancel"
    cmds.deleteUI("Gun_Select")


#Function to create wall
def createWall():
    wall = cmds.polyCube(h=10, w=15, d=1, name='wall')
    cmds.move(0,5,0, 'wall')



#Function to generate bullet spread
def bulletSpread(gunSelected, distance):
    weaponName = GunDictionary["weaponSelected"]
    multiplier = GunDictionary[weaponName + "_preset"][2]
    distance = distance
    newRange = distance * multiplier
    print newRange



    #Function to create drop-down menu in createSelectUI
def printNewMenuItem(item):
    print item
    GunDictionary["weaponSelected"] = item
    return GunDictionary["weaponSelected"]



    #Function to take weapon selected in UI1 and call UI2, also calls function to calculate bullet spread
def ui_refreshSelWeapon(fun, *args):
    createGunUI(GunDictionary["weaponSelected"])



    #UI allowing user to pick from a selection of Guns in a drop-down menu
def createSelectUI(): 
    cmds.window("Gun_Select")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    GunSelectCtrl = cmds.optionMenu(label='Gun', changeCommand=printNewMenuItem)
    for i in GunDictionary["weapon"]:
        cmds.menuItem(label=i)

    cmds.button(label = "Continue", command = ui_refreshSelWeapon)

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelSelect)

    cmds.showWindow("Gun_Select")

createSelectUI()

def refreshValues(*args):
    function = args[0]
    weapon = args[1]
    get01 = cmds.intSliderGrp(args[2],query=True, value=True)
    get02 = cmds.intSliderGrp(args[3],query=True, value=True)
    print get01, get02
    function(weapon, get01, get02)

weapon_uiDic = {}

#Called after gun select, allows user to choose the number of shots and distance from wall
def createGunUI(gunSelected):

    weaponName = GunDictionary["weaponSelected"]

    if cmds.window(weaponName, exists=True):
       cmds.deleteUI(weaponName)

    cmds.window(weaponName)
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Gun_Select")

    numBullets = GunDictionary[weaponName + "_preset"][0]
    distToTarget = GunDictionary[weaponName + "_preset"][1]

    weapon_uiDic["NumBulletsCtrl"] = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
                                                       minValue=numBullets[0], maxValue=numBullets[1], value=numBullets[2], field=True)

    weapon_uiDic["DistCtrl"] = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
                                                 minValue=distToTarget[0], maxValue=distToTarget[1], value=distToTarget[2], field=True)

    weapon_uiDic["fireButton"] = cmds.button(label = "Fire",  command = '')
    cmds.button(weapon_uiDic["fireButton"], e=1,                                      
                                            c=partial(refreshValues,
                                                      goShoot,
                                                      GunDictionary["weaponSelected"],
                                                      weapon_uiDic["NumBulletsCtrl"],
                                                      weapon_uiDic["DistCtrl"]))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow(weaponName)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have to query the value of the slider. Given the following example from the Maya help: http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/CommandsPython/intSliderGrp.html

```
window = cmds.window( title='intSliderGrp Example' )
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.intSliderGrp( field=True, label='Group 1' )
my_value = cmds.intSliderGrp( field=True, label='Group 2',     minValue=-10, maxValue=10, fieldMinValue=-100, fieldMaxValue=100, value=0 )
cmds.showWindow( window )

# Query the value
cmds.intSliderGrp(my_value, query=True, value=True)
```